# Dependency conflict

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am little bit confused. When I added `easy_localization` dependency  and run flutter pub get then I give following message:

```
Because easy_localization >=2.1.0+1 <2.3.4-nullsafety depends on flutter_localizations 
any from sdk which depends on path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1, 
easy_localization >=2.1.0+1 <2.3.4-nullsafety requires path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1.
```

I switched to Stable channel of Flutter and I have following Dart version:

```
Flutter 1.22.6 
Dart 2.10.5
```

Here is my fully pubspec file:

```
name: demo
description: demo

publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: 1.0.0
  flutter_bloc: 6.1.1
  equatable: 1.2.5
  easy_localization: 2.3.3+1

dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.16.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/translations/
```

I don't understand why I have dependency conflict. Also I tried remove .lock files. Do you have any ideas where is a problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, Just remove dependency version like this

```
  image_picker: 
  intl: 
  http: ^0.12.2
```

It will automatic choose version which is needed

Comment: Nice tip! Thanks!